# Rim dish and flange angle problem

Tags: wheels, rims, spokes, dynamo

this is the n-th time I have faced with this problem. The problem is than one flange of the rim is higher than another one. As you can see on the photo.

[image]
[image]

My rim is new this time, I have dynamo hub. Btw I faced with the same problem on simple hub not dynamo, so hub is not a problem. My hub is asymmetric, so one side should be tighten more than other one. 
To be clear right side is where power connector is and left is opposite side.
I tried make equal dish between hub locknuts. And in general wheel is quite okay, laterally and radially true, but this issue. 
Even if I have such result I still have to tighten right side as you can see on following photos, so If I do this right side flange will become even more higher than left.
I have some experience lacing wheels,so it is laced using 3-cross pattern correctly, but I have faced this problem several times, and don't know what is wrong. I mean I know that such result is because of one side is much tighten, but how to make correctly dished wheel and without such issue.
Also it is important to note that spokes are the same length, even wheel laced on the factory has spokes of the same length.
I can guess that if spoke on one side were shorter than on the other side everything would be okay, but by default wheel was laced using spokes of the same length.
[image]
[image]
Please help with this problem, how can I solve it, what is the reason of such result, maybe I should do something differntly ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it even before its laced and tensioned?

Comment: Stupid question:  How do you know your gauge is parallel to the axle?

Comment: (If you've had this problem "several times" then you're doing something wrong.)

Comment: Your truing stand looks as though everything is adjustable, so you can easily set it up with the axle at a funny angle and the gauge you're using to show that the rim is crooked can be set any old how. I think it would be almost impossible to get that stand to be actually square and straight to within 0.1 degrees or so, which is what you need to be able to say "the wheel is out". Like Criggie says, flip the wheel in the stand and see what it looks like. That will also tell you whether it's dished correctly.

Comment: Excellent use of photos too - thank you for supplying plenty of detail up-front.

Answer (score 8):

Simple idea - turn the wheel over in the truing stand.   The low side of the rim should move to the other side.

If the Right-hand side is still low after flipping, your gauge is out and needs calibrating.

Comment: Sorry for the short answer, but anything further would just be extraneous redundant waffle.

Comment: From the photos this what I suspect to be the case.

Comment: +1 Exactly this.  Given a rim has tension applied in the middle I can't see how build a true wheel with one side of the rim lower than the other, excluding of course a massive manufacturer defect. Different sized flanges won't change this as you adjust spoke length + tension for the flange size.